# How does bicubic interpolation work with MRI data?

Tags: image-processing, interpolation, medical, linear-interpolation, bicubic

I am trying to add slices to a stack of MRI images. I did a linear interpolation by calculating every new slice as the average of the immediate top and bottom slices. So while doing bicubic, do I just use 2 immediate top and bottom slices for an estimate of a new slice?

Comment: http://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic please check out this c++ implementation.

Answer (score 0):

in bicubic interpolation you must consider 16 adjacent pixels. the best way is using imresize function in MATLAB